# How can I call web service methods from javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, web-services, scriptmanager

Is there any way to call web services from javascript? I know you can add in a script manager to pull in the web services but I can't figure out how to access the functions from javascript once I've done that.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 11):

Please see [Calling Web Services from Client Script in ASP.NET AJAX](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/Tutorials/ConsumingWebServicesWithAJAXTutorial.aspx):

> This topic explains how to use to call
>   a Web service from ECMAScript
>   (JavaScript). To enable your
>   application to call ASP.NET AJAX Web
>   services by using client script, the
>   server asynchronous communication
>   layer automatically generates
>   JavaScript proxy classes. A proxy
>   class is generated for each Web
>   service for which an
>   `<asp:ServiceReference>` element is
>   included under the
>   `<asp:ScriptManager>` control in the
>   page.

Comment: That link is no longer valid. Try http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/Using%20Web%20Services%20in%20Ajax.ashx

Answer (score 2):

See [Using jQuery to Consume ASP.NET JSON Web Services](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) by Dave Ward.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "RSSReader.asmx/GetRSSReader",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      // Hide the fake progress indicator graphic.
      $('#RSSContent').removeClass('loading');

      // Insert the returned HTML into the <div>.
      $('#RSSContent').html(msg.d);
    }
  });
});
```