# How to Call A ASPNET web Service from javascript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

How to Call A ASPNET web Service from javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hai vaishu,

Have a look at these

[How do I call a web service from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118565/how-do-i-call-a-web-service-from-javascript)

[How can I call web service methods from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949688/how-can-i-call-web-service-methods-from-javascript)

http://www.asp.net/AJAX/Documentation/Live/Tutorials/ConsumingWebServicesWithAJAXTutorial.aspx

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/1081-Calling-WebServices-using-Javascript-ADVANCED.aspx