# How to call an ASP.Net Web Service in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

As the title states, I'm trying to call a web service written in ASP.Net (Same solution, but different project in visual studio) from javascript. Since I added the web reference for the service prior to this for calling it in VB.Net, I tried to use this reference by directly calling it.

In the body of the Default.aspx page, I have this code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
<Services>
<asp:ServiceReference Path="~/App_WebReferences/localhost/ServiceName.discomap" InlineScript="true" />
</Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

but in javascript, I can't call my service at all. Could anyone explain me how? I'd want to do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 alert(ServiceName.HelloWorld())
</script>
```

Comment: duplicate question with folloowing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949688/how-can-i-call-web-service-methods-from-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111234/calling-web-service-from-javascript-whats-it-doing-under-the-hood

Comment: This is a major feature of Ajax. Any Ajax tool will help you make web service calls and process the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found what I think is the right way to do it, it doesn't need jQuery at all, nor httprequest or any weird workaround. Here's the related code:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="WebService.asmx/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function callback(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        };

        function HelloWorld() {
            WebService.HelloWorld(callback);
        };
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="test" onclick="HelloWorld();">
        click this
    </div>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
      <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService.asmx" />
      </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to follow your solution to call webservices in ASP.NET in javascript. But I failed. Can you please give me some advice here (Thanks you very much): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976104/fail-to-call-webservices-in-asp-net-in-javascript