# Fail to Call WebServices in ASP.NET in Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-services

I fail to call a webservice. What have I miss? @@

I am trying to follow this instructions here: [How to call an ASP.Net Web Service in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106026/how-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service-in-javascript)

And below are my codes, but fails to work.

This is my webservice codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace Library
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]
    public class ReleaseSessionObject : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWord()
        {
            return "Hellow Word!";
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my ASP.NET page codes:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm6.aspx.cs" Inherits="Library.WebForm6" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <script src="ReleaseSessionObject.asmx" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HelloWorld() {
            try {
                var a = Library.ReleaseSessionObject.HelloWorld();
                alert(a);
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert(err.Message); 
            }
        };
    </script>

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
      <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/ReleaseSessionObject.asmx" />
      </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <input type="button" onclick="HelloWorld();" value="Click This" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

both ASP.NET page and Service files are located at the same folder.

but when I click on the button. It says: **undefined**

Answer (score 1):

Have you add web reference to your project? By doing so, the proxy will be created and then you can start consuming the web service methods. There's a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_web_services.htm) you might want to check out.

Also check out the [topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx) on MSDN as well.

Answer (score 1):

try making it async:

```
function HelloWorld() {
    Library.ReleaseSessionObject.HelloWorld(OnCompleted);
}

function OnCompleted(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your method in the web service asmx file says `HelloWord` but in the markup it says `HelloWorld`. It says undefined because it cannot find the method due to the spelling mistake.

If you do not succeed then try the following example:
[Calling ASMX web services directly from javascript](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2007/10/calling-asmx-web-services-directly-from.html)