# Can not get proper value in javascript from web service

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

Here is my problem:
I have a web service method which returns simple string:

```
namespace webStockService
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, 
    // using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class StockService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public string getChallenge()
        {
            //some codes
            return string;
        }
    }
```

I want to call this service in javascript:

```
try
{
   var challenge = webStockService.StockService.getChallenge();
}
catch(e)
{
   alert(e.messsage);
}
```

I have not got any error message in my call, but when I debug my script the challenge is `undefined`!!!

I have tested my web service method in asmx fashion and it invokes properly and returns string.

I also have inserted scriptManager tag in my html:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="webStockService" runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="StockService.asmx" />               
            </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of .net framework are you using?

Comment: @Amir check the answer posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line must be changed

<strike>var challenge = webStockService.StockService.getChallenge();</strike>

Please try the following

```
webStockService.StockService.getChallenge(SuccessCallBack);

function SuccessCallBack(returnedString)
{
  alert(returnedString);
}
```

You must pass a callback javascript function to execute. The call to webservice is asynchronous in nature and you won't get the intended behavior as you tried in your code. Reading about [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) will give you better idea. 
Detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106026/how-to-call-an-asp-net-web-service-in-javascript)